# Rainfall duration is continuous or discrete?

Tags: r, continuous-data, discrete-data

Let's say I have 38 years of hourly rainfall data. The volume is hourly recorded like this

```
volume = ..., 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9.4, 16.7...
```

Then, I'm using the IETD to extract the data into Volume and Duration.

```
Volume = 35.4, 46.3, 5.6, 1.5, 2.6, ...
Duration = 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, ...
for n = 4634
```

My question is the duration is continuous or discrete? is the original data is continuous? After using IETD, the data is continuous or discrete? Note that I don't know how the data is recorded and the data also available in daily

Comment: What are you doing and why? What is IETD?

Comment: Why would this matter? What kind of statistical model do you want to use?

Comment: Duration is continuous. Its measurement is continuous. *How those measurements are reported* is typically by rounding or binning them, which limits the results to a discrete set. It is useful to understand the distinctions between these three senses of the "continuous/discrete" dichotomy. It is even more useful to *avoid* letting questions of the "measurement type" of a variable guide your analysis (which is an approach frequently taught in schools, often by non-statisticians).  That approach is a relic of simpler times and a crutch that eventually should be thrown away.

Comment: I want to fit the data into a few distributions like Weibull, Gamma, Log-Normal, Exponential, and GEV. IETD is Inter-Event Time Definition. So I want to know if the duration is continuous or discrete? I assumed that the duration is continuous and fitted into these continuous distributions. @user2974951

Comment: This is matters because I want to fit the data into a few distributions as I mention above. Next, I want to fit the marginal distributions into copulas. @Tim

Comment: see my comments above. should I treat it as continuous/discrete? @whuber

Comment: All the distributions you name are continuous.  What you need to think about is what your data mean. Most likely they have been binned or rounded and that implies you need to use a *fitting procedure* that accommodates the effect of binning or rounding.  *That's* the kind of consideration that is important here--not the data type or measurement type.  It implies that the very first thing to do is consult the metadata for better information about what these numbers mean.

Comment: consult the metadata you mean to ask this question on Meta right? @whuber

Comment: Not at all. I mean that any decently curated dataset has documentation concerning what it means, where it came from, how it was processed, and how to interpret it.  That collection of information about the data is called [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata).